# Is the Fourier transform of $\exp(-\|x\|)$ non-negative?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Is the $n$-dimensional Fourier transform of $\exp(-\|x\|)$ always non-negative, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$? What is its support?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This Fourier transform is positive, supported everywhere, and has polynomial decay. It is the Poisson kernel evaluated at time 1, up to some rescaling.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel

Comment: Could you clarify? According to wikipedia, the Poisson kernel is supported on the unit disc, and there is no mention of a time parameter.

Comment: Never mind, I found it. Check the last section of the article, entitled "On the upper half-space". Thanks, Josh!

Answer (score 2):

These questions are closely related to the so-called stable distributions. In particular, 
the cauchy distribution on the real line has the characteristic function e^{-|x|}.

Go to the wikipedia page, and in the definition section set: 
mu=0      (this is the drift parameter) 
alpha=0   (this is the skewness parameter)

To get the same thing in higher dimensions, take independent copies in each coordinate.

Take note:  These distributions are not square integrable--otherwise the 'universal' Central 
Limit Theorem would hold.  The cauchy distribution is only weakly integrable.

Comment: Agreed that this works in one dimension, but for higher dimensions I think taking the product density doesn't always give the right formula (depending on the value of p)?

Comment: Mark Lewko and I had a discussion about this over here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/959/fourier-transform-of-exp-xp-more-general-question . I couldn't see how to make this strategy work in dimension greater than 1.
